# How to install Jenkins on Compute Engine at Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

i'dont really understand how to install something from GCP Marketplace to Compute Engine, which has been created already(windows servser). For instance i need to deploy Jenkins to practice with CI, but when i'm choosing that solution from Marketplace it's just deploying right below my VM in the list and looks like a separate process but i need this exactly on my RDP.

Comment: Have you considered [download](https://jenkins.io/download/)ing it on your instance?

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely there is a good Marketplace based solution for your use case.

Depending on the type of solution you pick off the Marketplace, you'll get different behavior.  Many of the solutions in the marketplace are self-contained -- they'll install the infrastructure they need to run, such as additional VMs.  This is done via [Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs).  They won't install on VMs you already have provisioned.  (This also lets the software and infrastructure be easily removed).

Others will just [provide a container](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/browse?filter=solution-type:container) which you can place on an already running VM (for example, [this jenkins package](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/jenkins2).  These will require more work on your part to manage and keep updated, of course (and obviously find a container that works on your windows machine if this is the route you want to go).  I don't currently see an obvious candidate in the market for Jenkins.

A third type of marketplaces package is "[click to deploy](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/partners/click-to-deploy-containers?)".  These will bring up a GKE cluster to run the containers on, but this likely isn't what you're looking for if you don't want additional VMs.